# How to add a new node to a blockchain from my web interface

Tags: contract-development, private-blockchain, eris-industries, monax

i want to create a **new account(user)** and add it to my **private blockchain** from my **web interface** ?

any exemple or idea please !

i work with eris platform

Comment: The title and the body of question have a little different sence. What do you really want, create a new node or create a new account(user)  from web interface  ?

Comment: @AlexeyBarsuk i want to create a new account (user) from web interface

Comment: so this answer is what you need http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13645/6041

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable personal API when launching your node

```
    geth --rpcapi="web3,personal" ....
```

2. You can create new account this way. Take a look at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal

```
    web3.personal.newAccount("account_password");
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a new account in blockchain from the web, run the geth instance in --rpc enabled.

Using the web3.js you can connect to the blockchain network and do all the commands we do in the geth console. Make sure cors enabled in geth.

But to start and stop new node itself, consider the below

I don't see a way to it directly.

But If you have an idea of Docker and swarm,

you all simply write a web app, with contains your metadata of the network like(genesis.json,networkid, port) you can initialize a node by writing sequence of commands like creating a docker container inside that install ethereum, geth then copy your genesis file start the node.

Using this you can create, delete, start, stop the node using your web application.